# Working with option and list in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I am having problems with recursive functions that takes a list and return an option list.  For example a function `all_except_one`:

```
val all_except_one : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list option = <fun>
```

Where the first occurrence of `'a` is removed from the list.  If the `'a` is not in the list you should return `None`.

without the option I have code that looks like this:

```
let same_string s1 s2 =
  s1 = s2

let rec all_except_one str str_l =
  match str_l with
  | [] -> []
  | hd::tl -> if same_string hd str
              then tl
              else hd::(all_except_one str tl)
```

but whenever I try and add the option, it gets in the way when doing my recursive call.

Comment: you should put your problematic code here as well, so we can see why `whenever you add the option, it gets in the way when doing recursive call`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to matching on the result of a recursive call is to write a helper function with an accumulator argument:

```
let remove_first elt list =
  let rec loop acc = function
    | [] -> None
    | x::xs ->
        if x = elt then Some (List.rev_append acc xs)
        else loop (x::acc) xs in
  loop [] list
```

A minor advantage of doing it this way is that the loop becomes tail recursive.

Answer (score 4):

An `option list` looks like `[ None; Some "abc"; None ]`. I think you want a `list option`, which looks like `Some ["a"; "b"; "c"]` or `None`.

As for your main question, you have to handle the recursive call by cases. If your recursive call returns None you would return None also. If the recursive call returns a `Some list`, you would return `Some (longer list)`. You also need to rethink the base case (when the list is empty), I would say.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't understand why you need `same_string` function, when you can use `=` instead.

I suggest to implement the function you want like this:

```
let rec all_except_one str str_l = match str_l with
  | [] -> None
  | hd :: tl -> if hd = str then Some tl else 
      match all_except_one str tl with
      | None -> None
      | Some x -> Some (hd :: x)
```

What caused a problem in your case?

Comment: This is great and close to what I was trying to implement.  I just couldn't figure out how to handle the option during the "else" part of the code.  The same_string was just from a set of sample problems I am trying to work out to teach myself ocaml.  I used it because they said to use it.  The problems build on each other so I am assuming they will have us modify it later.

Comment: Ok. Also if you want to use equals operator `=` as a function (basically, this is what you are doing when defining `same_string` like this), you can wrap it into brackets: `(=)`.